Type to navigate through object
I'm looking for a type that allows to describe any path through an object from the top (root) properties down to every leaf property as a string array and with the following characteristics:

The structure of the object is provided as interface / type
No forks, only a single path at a time
It shall allow to stop at any level
It shall not allow to select sibling or ancestor nodes in the next step, only direct children
If a property of the object holds an array, it shall allow to select a specific
array entry either via a predicate function or a numeric index, then it should be possible to continue based on the type of the array entries (homogeneous array is assumed)
It shall ignore optional properties in the sense of handling them as required for the typecheck
It shall support intellisense with only correct suggestions for auto completion
The type shall perform well also with large objects / types

The type doesn't have to be recursive, it would be okay if it has a limited number of nesting levels where the typing works and then falls back to "any" for deeper levels.
Also fine with using tricks that need lots of typing code, as long as it works.
An example to make it clearer:
// Interface for the predicate function used to pick an array element:
export type PredicateFunction<ArrayType> = (array: ArrayType, index?: number) => boolean;

interface State  {
    city: {
        name: string;
        inhabitants: {
            firstname: string;
            lastname: string;
        }[],
        districts: string[]
    }
}

// Valid "paths"
const path1 = ['city'];
const path4 = ['city', 'name'];
const path2 = ['city', 'inhabitants'];
const path3 = ['city', 'inhabitants', 1];
const path3 = ['city', 'inhabitants', inhabitant => inhabitant.firstname === 'Max', 'lastname'];

// Invalid "paths"
const invalidPath1 = ['name'];
const invalidPath2 = ['city', 'inhabitants', 'firstname'];
const invalidPath3 = ['inhabitants', 1, 'firstname'];


This valid path seems like it might not be possible.  const path3 = ['city', 'inhabitants', inhabitant => inhabitant.firstname === 'Max', 'lastname'];    Allowing an accessor function is an interesting problem.

This should be possible. I use the predicate function to address an entry in the array and then proceed stepping into the entries type.
Or do you see a contradiction to one of the rules defined that I missed? Thank you!

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but I've been recently trying to achieve something similar and came across this great blogpost that achieves what you are trying to do, however it separates keys in a string by a . instead of entries in an array.
Using a method, for a little type inference, you wouldn't need to create an interface for all your data structures either, depending on what your use case is.
The way I have been using the type from the blogpost is:
type NestedKeyOf<T, K = keyof T> = K extends keyof T & (string | number)
  ? `${K}` | (T[K] extends object ? `${K}.${NestedKeyOf<T[K]>}` : never)
  : never;

const deeply = {
  nested: {
    state: {
      isAvailable: true
    }
  }
}

function returnNestedValueOf<T extends {[key: string]: any}>(data: T, keys: NestedKeyOf<T>) {
    const separatedKeys = keys.split('.')
    let nested = data;

    separatedKeys.forEach((key: string) => {
        if (!!nested[key]) {
            nested = nested[key]
        }
    })

    return nested
}
// is { isAvailable: true }
const value = returnNestedValueOf(deeply, 'nested.state')

Here is a playground link.
EDIT: The problem with the above helper function however is that typescript believes that the entire original object is being returned. I don't know how to infer the nested value unfortunately.

Thank you bocaj, but I would really like to enable users typing the array directly and not using a helper function
